# ionSlideDidChange with react

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application using `Ionic framework 4` and `react`.
I am able to successfully implement slides.

What I'm looking for is to do some action on slide change. Ionic did provide an event to capture `ionSlideDidChange`, but there is no tutorial available on how to implement this event handler using react.

Highly appreciate any help on this is with example.

*My code is given below.*

```
<IonSlides scrollbar={true} options={slideOpts}>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <Beginning></Beginning>
                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 1</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                    </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>

                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 2</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                    </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>
                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 3</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                            </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>
                    </IonSlide>
                </IonSlides>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to include `onIonSlideDidChange={()=> console.log("SLIDES CHANGED")}` in the props of the  tag.

Eg/

```
<IonSlides scrollbar={true} options={slideOpts} onIonSlideDidChange={()=> console.log("SLIDES CHANGED")}>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <Beginning></Beginning>
                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 1</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                    </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>

                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 2</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                    </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>
                    </IonSlide>
                    <IonSlide>
                        <IonCard>
                            <IonCardHeader>
                                <IonCardSubtitle><strong>Slide 3</strong></IonCardSubtitle>
                                <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
                            </IonCardHeader>

                            <IonCardContent>
                                Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in a while,
                                and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
                            </IonCardContent>
                        </IonCard>
                    </IonSlide>
                </IonSlides>
```

This will post to the console every time a slide is changed. This can of course be pointed towards a method instead of a console log!

[image]

**Edit:**

A more substantial method (instead of console logging) would be to use one of the methods, such as getActiveIndex() which gives you the index of the current card;

```
const getIndex = async (event: any) => {
    let index: number = 0;
    await event.target.getActiveIndex().then((value: any) => (index=value));
    {console.log(index)}
    .......... do whatever with the index ..........
}
```

```
<IonSlides scrollbar={true} options={slideOpts} onIonSlideDidChange={(event: any)=> getIndex(event)}>
```

Comment: I'm using Ionic + React. There is any way to initialize the slide inside a function. I have a function which is called  goToSlide() and i  want use the slideTo method in this function but i nedd the initializitaion of the slide.